# Custom PCB Blink light in c

Tags: c++, c, circuit

Is there a way/tutorial to take a PCB (Printed Circuit Board) and make an LED Blink? Im basically asking:

1. Is there a DIY tutorial for making a mini os for a PCB (not Arduino like).
2. I want to put an LED on this PCB and I want to write in C/C++ a mini os that will make the light blink

2a. Tutorial/Video on this?

I have gone to the library, a college, and google and found no way to do this. Not a blog, a video or a useful tip. Anything will help!

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for [blinkenlights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights)!!!

Comment: You need some hardware first.. you need to get a chip - [PIC](http://www.microchip.com/) or [AVR](http://www.atmel.com), and a hardware programmer. Microchip's PICkit3 is pretty cheap and easy to use. Any ideas on your hardware choice yet? If you have a DIP (dual inline package; a chip with "legs") microprocessor, a breadboard, and a programmer, it's very easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SparkFun](http://www.sparkfun.com/) is a great resource for getting started with embedded design. [Here](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/category/1) is a whole series on Beginning Embedded Electronics with an AVR. [Here](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/93) is the article in that series where they tell you how to make an LED blink.

Answer (score 3):

O'Reilly published a book called [Programming Embedded Systems in C and C ++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565923546.do). The book dedicates an entire chapter to precisely this exercise (the chapter is called, not surprisingly, "Das Blinkenlights").